# How can I redirect user requests (i.e. when a user refreshes a page) to index.html in my Flask app?

Tags: reactjs, flask

I have built a Flask/React app and am trying to host it on Heroku to begin with. In preparation for this, I have built the React app with npm run build and copied the contents of the build folder to a 'static' folder in my backend folder (see the folder structure below). I have largely set up routes for serving static files correctly as when I run the Flask app and go to localhost:5000 it works and allows me to navigate throughout the app correctly, including updating the SQLite database on my machine correctly. However, if I refresh the page on any page except localhost:5000/ (say localhost:5000/account), it returns a Not Found HTML page instead. To clarify, if I open my browser and try to directly visit localhost:5000/account I get the same response. I have tried to sort this with a catch-all function but it is not working. Any ideas on how to sort?

Folder structure:

```
backend
| app.py
| other files (requirements.txt etc)
| static
|   | index.html
|   | manifest.json
|   | other individual files (favicon etc)
|   | css (folder)
|   | js (folder)
|   | media (folder)
```

```
# Routes to serve static files
@app.route('/static/css/<path:filename>')
def serve_css(filename):
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static', 'css'), filename)

@app.route('/static/js/<path:filename>')
def serve_js(filename):
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static', 'js'), filename)

@app.route('/static/media/<path:filename>')
def serve_media(filename):
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static', 'media'), filename)

# Optionally, you may need to serve other static files (e.g., favicon, manifest, robots.txt)
@app.route('/<path:filename>')
def serve_other_static_files(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, filename)


@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def catch_all(path):
    # Attempt to serve the file directly from the static folder
    logging.info(f"Requested path: {path}")
    file_path = os.path.join(app.static_folder, path)
    logging.info(f"Resolved file path: {file_path}")
    # Check if the file exists and then decide what to do
    # Since you're always returning index.html for testing, log that decision
    return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, 'index.html')
```